# Deep Freeze Workstation not responding on install

Tags: workstation, deep-freeze

I'm trying to install Deep Freeze Enterprise on a series of computers. My understanding is that I should be able to install the administrator and console tool on a primary machine, and then the workstation seed/full on the other machines. I can then load an image to the other machines.

Unfortunately, I when I try to install either the workstation seed, or the workstation full, the installation hangs.

[image: Installation not responding]

This happens whether I try to install it on the computer with the console/administrator, or on a computer without anything deep freeze related.

Why is the happening? What steps am I missing to install a deep freeze workstation?

Comment: You have contacted their support team?

Comment: @Ramhound I have not. I have solved though, I guess. The key is just to run the silent install. I will post that as an answer shortly.